# Can thor accept unix-like options (such as -lv)?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, thor

I've recently started using thor. I've set my script up with some global options, such as `-l` `--logging` and `-v` `--verbose`. I'd like users to be able to call my thor task with `-lv` rather than `-l -v`, but this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are several items in the standard library and should help you support Unixy flags/command-line arguments:

[getoptlong](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/index.html) is reminiscent of Perl's GetOpt library, so if you've used that (or one of the many clones in other languages) that may be easy for you.

Otherwise, [optparse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html) is more Ruby-ish, and thus might feel more natural to use.

Comment: You're suggesting that I use those instead of thor or in conjunction with it?